# Using sqlite database in c# project and create setup

Tags: c#, installshield-le

I am trying to use Sqlite database in my C# project and I done this well in IDE. My problem is when I make setup package for my project and I install it, the program can't access to the sqlite database. Also I know it is because the user doesn't have permission to access file, and when I run program as administrator the problem is solved.

My questions is, how can I use sqlite database in my project so that the program to be executed without administrator permission after installation?

I am using Installshield Limited Edition to deploy my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if you wrap the database in an installer, it will extract to Program Files, in which you might have problems accessing for write access with certain users.

InstallShield should have a special pseudo folder to pop the datafile in AppData. You'll also need to change your program so that it expects to find the database there.

I can't quite remember the details I'm afraid.

Mark